# ie9 html5 audio play with volume setted

Tags: html, audio, volume

i want to play an html5 audio with a setted volume=0.2, to be able to change the volume later while the audio plays.

it works for all html5 browser but ie9:
internet explorer starts playing audio with volume=1 and after 1/2 second the volume set has its effect.

```
<audio id="mytrack" preload="auto" metadata>
    <source src="audio/audio2.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="audio/audio2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

<div id="play">play</div>

 <script src="javascript/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var track = $('#mytrack').get(0);

    $('#play').click(function(){
        track.volume="0.2",
        track.play();
    });
 });
```